# Xamarin forms BoxView animation

Tags: animation, custom-controls, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a blinking BoxView. I created a BlinkingBoxView that extends BoxView and added 1 Boolean property called "Blink". So what I want is, every time Blink changes and it's value is true, I want to start the blinking animation, if the value is false stop the animation.

Do I need to do this in C# code, or can I use only XAML like WPF?

Here is my try...

```
public class BlinkingBoxView : BoxView
{
    public BlinkingBoxView() 
        : base()
    {

    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty BlinkProperty = BindableProperty.Create<BlinkingBoxView, bool>(w => w.Blink, default(bool), BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public bool Blink
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(BlinkProperty); }
        set 
        {
            SetValue(BlinkProperty, value);

            var blinkAnimation = new Animation(d => this.FadeTo(0, 750, Easing.Linear)).WithConcurrent(new Animation(d => this.FadeTo(1, 750, Easing.Linear)));

            if (this.Blink)
                this.Animate("Blink", blinkAnimation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? I don't really understand it.

Comment: I want blink the BoxView and keep it blinking if 1 property of the BoxView is true. Until that property is true the boxview should appear and disappear (flhasing). If the property becomes false, it stops the animation and the boxview appears normally. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `OnPropertyChanged` override to catch properties changes:

```net
public class BlinkingBoxView : BoxView
{
    volatile bool isBlinking;

    public static readonly BindableProperty BlinkProperty = BindableProperty.Create<BlinkingBoxView, bool>(w => w.Blink, default(bool), BindingMode.OneWay);

    public bool Blink
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(BlinkProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BlinkProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty BlinkDurationProperty = BindableProperty.Create<BlinkingBoxView, uint>(w => w.BlinkDuration, 500, BindingMode.OneWay);

    public uint BlinkDuration
    {
        get
        {
            return (uint)GetValue(BlinkDurationProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BlinkDurationProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == BlinkProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            SetBlinking(Blink);
        }
        if (propertyName == BlinkDurationProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            if (isBlinking)
            {
                SetBlinking(false);
                SetBlinking(Blink);
            }
        }
    }

    void SetBlinking(bool shouldBlink)
    {
        if (shouldBlink && !isBlinking)
        {
            isBlinking = true;

            var blinkAnimation = new Animation(((d) => {
                Opacity = d;
            }), 0f, 1f, Easing.SinInOut);

            this.Animate("BlinkingBoxViewBlink", blinkAnimation, length: BlinkDuration, repeat: () => isBlinking);
        }
        else if (!shouldBlink && isBlinking)
        {
            isBlinking = false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it in XAML just the same as any other `View`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to follow some tutorials/ read the documentation and I couldn't get this. Thanks